# upstart init script remains on apt-get remove

Tags: apt, application-development, packaging, upstart

I just created my first .deb file ever from a Python script. I included a package.upstart file under package/debian and all installed great.

However, I noticed that `apt-get remove package` leaves the upstart script there.

I tested this functionality by removing another program that has an upstart script, and this does seem to be normal behaviour but I would like to confirm this. Is this normal behaviour?

Isn't it bad that the upstart script will be trying to run my program on every boot of a user's machine even if they have removed my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apt-get remove` only removes the packages, it does not remove the associated configuration files of the package.

`apt-get purge` is the command snippet you use if you also want to remove a package's configuration files. Test your application with that and that should get you the result you need.

See also:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto
- [manpage for the `apt-get` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get)